# GeoJSON MultiLineString import to MySQL with SRID/CRS 27700, 'out of range'

Tags: mysql, geometry, geojson, srid

Version 8.0.20
I'm importing a single link of the OSM road network with the intention of creating a buffer in MySQL.

This is it:

```
select st_srid(st_geomfromgeojson('{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "osm_id": "200020986" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 440417.0, 192697.0 ], [ 440386.0, 192596.0 ], [ 440361.0, 192416.0 ], [ 440353.0, 192277.0 ], [ 440331.0, 192121.0 ], [ 440327.0, 192040.0 ], [ 440330.0, 191981.0 ], [ 440341.0, 191949.0 ], [ 440433.0, 191817.0 ], [ 440494.0, 191703.0 ], [ 440506.0, 191688.0 ] ] ] } }'),27700)
into @foo
```

- the easting and northings are within OSGB
- the srid is being defined as 27700

and yet I get back

> Error Code: 3616. Longitude 440417.000000 is out of range in function st_geomfromgeojson. It must be within (-180.000000, 180.000000].

It looks like its ignoring the 27700 and trying to encode into 4326/WGS84 and clearly failing.
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've found to work around this to use ogr2ogr to import the eastings and northings (in a geojson file). An example code would be as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:test,user=root import_file_location \
-nln FILENAME -update -overwrite -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=MULTIPOLYGON
```

This will import as British National Grid coordinates, which can then be used to create buffers in MySQL.